# Encapsulating Unicode from redis

Tags: python, unicode, redis

In this first example we save two Unicode strings in a file while delegating to codecs the task of encoding them.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
cities = [u'Düsseldorf', u'天津市']
with codecs.open("cities", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    for c in cities:
        f.write(c)
```

We now do the same thing, first saving the two names to redis, then reading them back and saving what we've read to a file. Because what we've read is already in `utf-8` we skip decoding/encoding for that part.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import redis
r_server = redis.Redis('localhost') #, decode_responses = True)
cities_tag = u'Städte'
cities = [u'Düsseldorf', u'天津市']
for city in cities:
    r_server.sadd(cities_tag.encode('utf8'),
                  city.encode('utf8'))

with open(u'someCities.txt', 'w') as f:
    while r_server.scard(cities_tag.encode('utf8')) != 0:
        city_utf8 = r_server.srandmember(cities_tag.encode('utf8'))
        f.write(city_utf8)
        r_server.srem(cities_tag.encode('utf8'), city_utf8)
```

How can I replace the line

```
r_server = redis.Redis('localhost')
```

with

```
r_server = redis.Redis('localhost', decode_responses = True)
```

to avoid the wholesale introduction of .encode/.decode when using redis?

Comment: unrelated: [use `io.open()` instead of `codecs.open()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0400/#abstract)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a problem.

If you remove all of the `.encode('utf8')` calls in your code it produces a correct file, i.e. the file is the same as the one produced by your current code.

```
>>> r_server = redis.Redis('localhost')
>>> r_server.keys()
[]
>>> r_server.sadd(u'Hauptstädte', u'東京', u'Godthåb',u'Москва')
3
>>> r_server.keys()
['Hauptst\xc3\xa4dte']
>>> r_server.smembers(u'Hauptstädte')
set(['Godth\xc3\xa5b', '\xd0\x9c\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0', '\xe6\x9d\xb1\xe4\xba\xac'])
```

This shows that keys and values are UTF8 encoded, therefore `.encode('utf8')` is not required. The default encoding for the `redis` module is UTF8. This can be changed by passing an encoding when creating the client, e.g. `redis.Redis('localhost', encoding='iso-8859-1')`, but there's no reason to.

If you enable response decoding with `decode_responses=True` then the responses will be converted to unicode using the client connection's encoding. This just means that you don't need to explicitly decode the returned data, `redis` will do it for you and give you back a unicode string:

```
>>> r_server = redis.Redis('localhost', decode_responses=True)
>>> r_server.keys()
[u'Hauptst\xe4dte']
>>> r_server.smembers(u'Hauptstädte')
set([u'Godth\xe5b', u'\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430', u'\u6771\u4eac'])
```

So, in your second example where you write data retrieved from redis to a file, if you enable response decoding then you need to open the output file with the desired encoding. If this is the default encoding then you can just use `open()`. Otherwise you can use `codecs.open()` or manually encode the data before writing to the file.

```
import codecs

cities_tag = u'Hauptstädte'
with codecs.open('capitals.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    while r_server.scard(cities_tag) != 0:
        city = r_server.srandmember(cities_tag)
        f.write(city + '\n')
        r_server.srem(cities_tag, city)
```