# Distinction between str and unicode: why does Redis return binary data when passed unicode?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, redis

After [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618833/increased-understanding-of-unicode-in-python-2-7) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709765/encapsulating-unicode-from-redis) regarding the distinction between the datatypes `str` and `unicode`, I'm still puzzled at the following.

In Block 1 we see that the type of the city is `unicode`, as we're expecting.

Yet in Block 2, after a round-trip through disk (redis), the type of the city is `str` (and the representation is different).

The [dogma](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) of storing `utf-8` on disk, reading into `unicode`, and writing back in `utf-8` is failing somewhere.

Why is the second instance of `type(city)` `str` rather than `unicode`?

Just as importantly, does it matter? Do you care whether your variables are `unicode` or `str`, or are you oblivious to the difference just so long as the code "does the right thing"?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Block 1
city = u'Düsseldorf'
print city, type(city), repr(city)
# Düsseldorf <type 'unicode'> u'D\xfcsseldorf'

# Block 2
import redis
r_server = redis.Redis('localhost')
r_server.set('city', city)
city = r_server.get('city')
print city, type(city), repr(city)
# Düsseldorf <type 'str'> 'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf'
```

Comment: Well, it means that the Redis API returns a binary `str` and not a Unicode object. There's nothing necessarily wrong, it's just what the API does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599147/save-unicode-in-redis-but-fetch-error

Comment: You should watch the talk given by Ned Batchelder on ["pragmatic unicode"](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: @mgilson I did. That's the dogma I'm referring to. (I'm not using that word disparagingly, merely to signal that it's useful to distill his advice until one understands enough how "to unicode" one's code throughout.)

Comment: @Calaf -- Ah, so you did.  Sorry, I didn't follow the link.  In this case, you'd probably want to decode into bytes when you server.set and then encode the result:  `r_server.set('city', city.decode('utf-8')); city = r_server.get('city').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @mgilson  What would you advise someone who naïvely already wrote substantial code while having the most marginal concept of what unicode entails, and then learned unicode afterwards. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35712646/704972 makes it conceivable that retroactively fitting unicode on non-unicoded code may be doable without peppering the code with .decode(..)/.encode(..). I'm still vainly hoping it's true!

Comment: @Calaf -- I don't deal with unicode a whole lot, so I'm probably not the best one to answer your question ... With that said, I've definitely felt the pain of not handling unicode well in my codebases so I think that the effort to go through and make the unicode sandwiches is worth it.  Looking at that post, it appears that `redis`'s `decode_responses` might help make that easier (you don't need to do the decoding yourself).

Comment: @Calaf I think you got the encode and decode swapped, you can encode `u'Düsseldorf'` to bytes, and decode when reading back. Note that Python 3 will raise an error if you make these mistakes, which makes debugging any problems a lot easier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Dogma?

It's not dogmatic why character sets and encodings are used - it's a necessity. 
Hopefully, you will have read enough to understand why we have so many character sets in use. Unicode is obviously the way forward (having all characters mapped), but how do you transfer a Unicode character from one machine to another, or save it to disk?

We could use the Unicode point value, but as Unicode points are effectively 32bits, each character would need to be saved/transferred as the whole 32bits (aka UTF-32). `a` would be encoded as `0x00000061` - that's a lot of wasted bits just for one character. UTF-16 is a little less wasteful when dealing with mostly ASCII, but UTF-8 is the best compromise by using the least amount of bits.

Using decoded Unicode within code obviously frees developers from having to consider the intricacies of encoding, such as how many bytes equal a character.

### Solutions

#### Redis Client

As suggested by @J.F.Sebastian, the redis-py driver includes a `decode_responses` option on the `Redis` and `Connection` classes. When set to `True` the client will decode the responses using the `encoding` option. By default `encoding = utf-8`.

E.g.

```
r_server = redis.Redis('localhost', decode_responses=True)
city = r_server.get('city')
# city = <type 'unicode'>
```

#### Wrapper Class

No longer required since discovery of `decode_responses`.

It would appear that the Redis driver is rather simplistic - it so happens that if you send a Unicode it'll convert it to the default encoding (UTF-8 is most cases). On response, Redis doesn't know the encoding so returns an `str` for you to decode as appropriate.

Therefore, if would be safer to encode your strings to UTF-8 before sending to Redis and decode as UTF-8 on response. Other DB drivers are more advanced, so receive and return Unicodes.

But of course, you shouldn't be peppering your code with `.encode()` and `.decode()`. The common approach is to form "Unicode sandwiches", so that external data is decoded to Unicode on input and encoded on output. So how does that work for you? **Wrap the Redis driver** so that it returns what you want, thereby pushing the decoding back into the periphery of your code.

For example, it should be as simple as:

```
class UnicodeRedis(redis.Redis):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "encoding" in kwargs:
            self.encoding = kwargs["encoding"]
        else:
            self.encoding = "utf-8"
        super(UnicodeRedis, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(UnicodeRedis, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(result, str):
            return result.decode(self.encoding)
        else:
            return result
```

You can then interact with it as normal except that you can pass an `encoding` argument that changes how strings are decoded. If you don't set `encoding`, this code will assume `utf-8`.

E.g.

```
r_server = UnicodeRedis('localhost')
city = r_server.get('city')
```

Comment: 1- A byte is as much an abstraction as a Unicode codepoint (consider any network API on a system where a byte is not octet). OS can provide Unicode API for files, network, etc (Windows does it in many cases). And it is certainly a deficiency that Redis  Python bindings return  text as binary blobs.  2- `sys.maxunicode.bit_length()` is beside the point here e.g., Python 3.3+ uses a flexible internal representation. Or even simpler: a library can provide Unicode API while encoding/decoding internally to whatever representation is the most useful in a particular case (as your `UnicodeRedis` does)

Comment: Passing `decode_responses=True` could be used instead encoding/decoding manually in UnicodeRedis.

Comment: Ah, thanks @J.F.Sebastian. I searched high and low for such a property.

Comment: By "dogma" I meant "a tidbit of useful, easily remembered, knowledge", and not, as you seem to have interpreted, as less than very accurate or unnecessary one. :)

Comment: Sorry @calaf, I understand "dogma" as defined here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dogma . If only dogma was just a tidbit of useful :)

Comment: where is "encoding" declared in the line "return result.decode(encoding)"

Comment: @Yijin good spot - I neglected the `self` namespace. It should read: `self.encoding`. I've now fixed the code sample

Comment: @Yijin I've now updated the answer to use J.F.Sebastian's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As J.F. Sebastian stated, redis-py API supports decoding responses to unicode by setting `decode_response=True` in the **init** method of redis.Redis class.